# How to I create a nested for loop ping sweeper?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, ping

OK so I'm a complete newb when it comes to programming, (The only languages I have experience with Javascript, SQL, and a little visual basic from a college course.)
Anyway, I'm taking a SANS security/Ethical Hacking course and one of the useful little tidbits I learned was creating a ping sweeper in Windows Command Prompt:

```
for /L %i in (1,1,255) do @ping -n 1 10.10.10.%i | find "TTL"
```

Now what I want to do is not only iterate through the fourth octet but the third octet and second octet as well. The power point from the SANS class said this was possible with a nested for loop and other variables (%j, %k) but they didn't show an example of how to to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you find when you googled "nested for loop?"

Comment: i found other examples but none that fit what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the concept in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,255) do (
    for /L %%j in (1,1,255) do (
        for /L %%k in (1,1,255) do (
            for /L %%l in (1,1,255) do (
                echo %%i.%%j.%%k.%%l
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Or this [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) one-liner

```
for /L %i in (1,1,255) do for /L %j in (1,1,255) do for /L %k in (1,1,255) do for /L %l in (1,1,255) do echo %i.%j.%k.%l
```

---

Explanation:

- **Step 1:** `@echo off` removes this prompt - `C:\...>`
- **Step 2:** The four `for` loop loops from 1 to 255 individually.
- **Step 3:** Combining them
- **Step 4:** Loops starts from 1.1.1.1

  - Then to the next IP 1.1.1.2
  - All the way to 255.255.255.255

    - **Step 5:** `echo` the looping IP address

Comment: or if you insist on doing it directly on command line, use this monster:  `for /L %i in (1,1,255) do for /L %j in (1,1,255) do for /L %k in (1,1,255) do for /L %l in (1,1,255) do echo %i.%j.%k.%l`

Comment: @Stephan I changed from %%x to %x because the question uses command-line for metavariable, not batch-file metavariable, yeah, and I hate cmd.exe doesn't support multi-line input

Comment: `@echo off` and the formatting clearly indicate that this would be a batchfile, so I "corrected" the syntax. It's your choice to roll back to your version.

Comment: @Stephan Your edit was correct, so I leave it there. But I also included your one-liner method.